# spring-data-jdbc update with repository save methods updates ID

Tags: java, spring-data-jdbc

Calling **CrudRepository save()** method for an entity that is NOT new creates following sql: **UPDATE card SET id = ?, customer_id = ? ... WHERE id = ?**

This raises exception **Cannot update identity column 'id'**

ID is generated by the database

used version: 1.0.6.RELEASE & 1.0.9.RELEASE

DB: mssql

Why is update statement trying to update the ID column as it is the primary key?

Entity:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Table("card")
public class Card {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column("customer_id")
    private String customerId;
...
```

Repository:

```
public interface CardRepository extends CrudRepository<Card, String> {
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the problem, but consider changing your repository to a `CrudRepository<Card, Long>` , because the second parameter should be the type of the id column.

Comment: @Arnaud thank you for noticing that. Unfortunately i did not resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-262 which was fixed and released in version `1.1.M1` the current version of that development branch is `1.1.RC1`.

Switching to that version should solve the problem.

*Note: I've seen the exception you mention only with MS-SqlServer which isn't yet fully supported yet.*

Comment: MSSQL is the database. Probably that is the issue. I have seen that there is different class Column on master branch on github( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/master/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/convert/SqlGenerator.java ). Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you haven't set id generation Strategy for the ID. 
Add this and try if it is working.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Comment: that is jpa(hibernate) focused statement, not spring-data-jdbc statement